# system defined environment variable in .env file

Tags: laravel, dotenv

I have a system environment variable 
**DB_USR = dbusr**

When i do,

echo $DB_USR in the shell terminal,

it returns **dbusr**

Now, can i call this varibale from .env file in php as below?

DB_USERNAME=$DB_USR

The reason for this is that i am setting system wide environment variable through kubernetes deployment file to avoid the secrets being stored in docker image.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

PHP Version: 7.2
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks,
NG

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, so totally untested... but you *should* be able to do this like so in your `.env` file:

```
DB_USERNAME=${DB_USR}
```

**update**

Alright, so the above didn’t work so let’s fallback to using [`getenv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

You’ll need to update your `config/database.php` file to grab the database user from `getenv(‘DB_USR’)` rather than `env(‘DB_USERNAME’)`.

Comment: I still getting error like this , {"http_code":400,"message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '${DB_USR}'@'172.20.20.20' (using password: YES)